Copy PDF file to clipboard using its path
I'm trying to copy a PDF file that is located in a specific directory on the system and leave it on the clipboard to be pasted when the user presses CTRL+V.
I don't see a way to do that! Only with strings or html, for example (as is the case with the Clipboard API:
const { clipboard } = require('electron')

clipboard.writeText('Example string', 'selection')
console.log(clipboard.readText('selection'))

Is there any way to exchange the string "example string" for a string containing the path to the file and then have it copied to the clipboard as a file, and not as a string?
